# Extra line depending on input for mailing in Word

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have an Excel sheet with company names, contacts, address,... used for a mailing document in
Word. Ideally the address at the top should be:

```
{MERGEFIELD «company»}
to {MERGEFIELD «contact»}
{MERGEFIELD «street»} 
{MERGEFIELD «city»}
```

But it's possible that there's no "contact" person known up there and then the address should be:

```
{MERGEFIELD «company»}
{MERGEFIELD «street»} 
{MERGEFIELD «city»}
```

I wanted to use the "if" statement where it would be something like:

```
if ( {MERGEFIELD «contact»} <> "")
  {MERGEFIELD «company»} + "\b" + "to "+ {MERGEFIELD «contact»}
else
  {MERGEFIELD «company»}
```

But I can't get it working, I don't understand how Word splits the if-statement.

this works:

```
{ IF {MERGEFIELD «company»} <> "" {MERGEFIELD «contact»} {MERGEFIELD «company» }}
```

but if I add "to" it's not working anymore (and I don't know the newline tag neither)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That's as simple as:

```
{MERGEFIELD «company»}{MERGEFIELD «contact» \b "¶
to "}
{MERGEFIELD «street»} 
{MERGEFIELD «city»}
```

where the ¶ is a real paragraph break or line break.

Comment: And how do you type that "¶" symbol ? Just with an enter or you have to add it as a special symbol ?

Comment: As I said: «the ¶ is a real paragraph break or line break». So you press either <enter> or <Shift-Enter>, depending on which of those alternatives you want.